# How to divide a result set into equal parts?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table `new_table`

```
ID   PROC_ID     DEP_ID    OLD_STAFF   NEW_STAFF
1      15          43         58          ?  
2      19          43         58          ?
3      29          43         58          ?
4      31          43         58          ?
5      35          43         58          ?
6      37          43         58          ?
7      38          43         58          ?
8      39          43         58          ?
9      58          43         58          ? 
10     79          43         58          ?
```

How I can select all proc_ids and update new_staff, for example

```
ID   PROC_ID     DEP_ID    OLD_STAFF   NEW_STAFF
1      15          43         58          15  
2      19          43         58          15
3      29          43         58          15
4      31          43         58          15
5      35          43         58          23
6      37          43         58          23
7      38          43         58          23
8      39          43         58          28
9      58          43         58          28 
10     79          43         58          28


15 - 4(proc_id)
23 - 3(proc_id)
28 - 3(proc_id)
58 - is busi
```

where 15, 23, 28 and 58 staffs in one dep

Comment: And the logic is? How do you decide what row to update with 15, 23, .. ?

Comment: row is not important, it's important to be updated equal, example i have 3 staff and 12 proc_id, I want update every 4 proc_id

Comment: So where do the values `15`, `23`, etc come from? Why mention `58` when it's not used in the final output? There's nothing in the posted data to explain this.

Answer (score 2):

> "how to divide equal parts"

Oracle has a function, `ntile()` which splits a result set into equal buckets. For instance this query puts your posted data into four buckets:

```
SQL> select id
  2        , proc_id
  3        , ntile(4) over (order by id asc) as gen_staff
  4  from new_table;

        ID    PROC_ID  GEN_STAFF
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         15          1
         2         19          1
         3         29          1
         4         31          2
         5         35          2
         6         37          2
         7         38          3
         8         39          3
         9         58          4
        10         79          4

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This isn't quite the solution you want but you need to clarify your requirements before it's possible to provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   update new_table
   set new_staff='15'
   where ID in('1','2','3','4')

   update new_table
   set new_staff='28'
   where ID in('8','9','10')

   update new_table
   set new_staff='23'
   where ID in('5','6','7')
```

Not sure if this is what you mean.